# How can I write an array values to different paragraphs in a html document using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please, I want to print out the contents of an array to different blocks of paragraphs in HTML using javascript or jquery. I can console.log the problem but can write all individually to different paragraphs of the HTML document I need that to appear at.[my source code screenshot in js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhR3L.png)

```js
// Latest
$(document).each(function() {
  var price = [];
  var oldprice = [];
  var discount;
  var i;
  $('.price').children('p').each(function() {
    price.push(this.innerHTML);
  });
  $('.old-price').children('p').each(function() {
    oldprice.push(this.innerHTML);
  });
  $(function(){
    for(i=0;i <= ((oldprice.length)&&(price.length));i++) {
      var mainprice = price[i].replace("₦",""); //new price
      mainprice = parseFloat(mainprice.replace(",",""));
      var oldmainprice = oldprice[i].replace("₦",""); //oldprice
      oldmainprice = parseFloat(oldmainprice.replace(",",""));

      var disc = oldmainprice - mainprice;
      var pectDisc = (disc / oldmainprice) * 100;
      pectDisc = parseInt(pectDisc);
      // console.log("-" + pectDisc + "%");
      var prices = [];
      var offs = [];

      prices.push(pectDisc);
      for(var x in prices) {
        if($(".off")) {
          $(".off").text("-" + prices[x] + "%");
          // console.log(prices[x]);
        }
      }
    };//end of for loop
  });
});
```

```html
                      <div class="asses-product">
                        <div class="pd">
                          <div class="img"><img src="img/Products/laptop.png" alt="product-image"></div>
                          <div class="product-description">
                            <div class="product-name"><h4><a href="#">Hp Laptop Envy 14</a></h4></div>
                            <div class="price"><p>₦ 256,000</p></div>
                            <div class="old-price"><p>₦ 300,000</p></div>
                            <div class="off"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pd">
                          <div class="img"><img src="img/Products/printer.png" alt="product-image"></div>
                          <div class="product-description">
                            <div class="product-name"><h4><a href="#">Hp printer series 10</a></h4></div>
                            <div class="price"><p>₦ 12,500</p></div>
                            <div class="old-price"><p>₦ 18,000</p></div>
                            <div class="off"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all that with this code:

```
$(".product-description").each(function () {
    // Get price within this container, and remove all non-digits
    let price = $(".price", this).text().replace(/\D/g, ""); 
    let oldprice = $(".old-price", this).text().replace(/\D/g, ""); 
    let disc = oldprice - price;
    let pectDisc = Math.floor((disc / oldprice) * 100);
    $(".off", this).text("-" + pectDisc + "%");
});
```

This will treat each block with class "product-description" one by one (since they don't effect each other's result). Within those blocks you can retrieve the elements you need by limiting the scope to `this`.

Digits can be extracted easily by removing anything that is not a digit. The regular expression `\D` matches any non-digit.

Don't use `parseInt` to remove decimals from a number. Use `Math.floor` instead, which avoids the unnecessary string-conversion that `parseInt` applies.

Some of the errors in your code:

The end-condition of the outer `for` loop is wrong:

```
i < ((oldprice.length)&&(price.length))
```

This should be:

```
i < oldprice.length && i < price.length
```

... and really, both lengths should be the same, so you could have simplified to:

```
i < oldprice.length
```

Another error is the inner `for` loop. It does not get to the right `.off` element. It always selects them all, and sets them all to the *same* text. Instead, your code should have retrieved the *right* instance among the many `.off` elements, and only set the text of that one.

You could have fixed that by replacing that inner loop with this code:

```
$(".off").eq(i).text("-" + prices[x] + "%");
```

But all in all, I think the approach I have taken at the start of my answer is better: instead of collecting the prices in an array, just deal with each section one by one.

Comment: Thanks this worked I will study it to understand more. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is on your for loop condition.

Your array has 2 element but your condition has 3 loop. so change `<=` condition to `<`.

```
for(i=0;i < ((oldprice.length)&&(price.length));i++) {
```

see snippet:

```js
// Latest
$(document).each(function() {
  var price = [];
  var oldprice = [];
  var discount;
  var i;
  $('.price').children('p').each(function() {
    price.push(this.innerHTML);
  });
  $('.old-price').children('p').each(function() {
    oldprice.push(this.innerHTML);
  });
  $(function(){
     for(i=0;i < ((oldprice.length)&&(price.length));i++) {
      var mainprice = price[i].replace("₦",""); //new price
      mainprice = parseFloat(mainprice.replace(",",""));
      var oldmainprice = oldprice[i].replace("₦",""); //oldprice
      oldmainprice = parseFloat(oldmainprice.replace(",",""));

      var disc = oldmainprice - mainprice;
      var pectDisc = (disc / oldmainprice) * 100;
      pectDisc = parseInt(pectDisc);
      // console.log("-" + pectDisc + "%");
      var prices = [];
      var offs = [];

      prices.push(pectDisc);
      for(var x in prices) {
        if($(".off")) {
          $(".off").text("-" + prices[x] + "%");
          // console.log(prices[x]);
        }
      }
    };//end of for loop
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="asses-product">
                        <div class="pd">
                          <div class="img"><img src="img/Products/laptop.png" alt="product-image"></div>
                          <div class="product-description">
                            <div class="product-name"><h4><a href="#">Hp Laptop Envy 14</a></h4></div>
                            <div class="price"><p>₦ 256,000</p></div>
                            <div class="old-price"><p>₦ 300,000</p></div>
                            <div class="off"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pd">
                          <div class="img"><img src="img/Products/printer.png" alt="product-image"></div>
                          <div class="product-description">
                            <div class="product-name"><h4><a href="#">Hp printer series 10</a></h4></div>
                            <div class="price"><p>₦ 12,500</p></div>
                            <div class="old-price"><p>₦ 18,000</p></div>
                            <div class="off"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```